# How to set SELECT default privileges in PostgreSQL schema for new tables?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to grant `SELECT` privileges in a specific schema to a specific user. I use the following command:

```
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA myschema TO myuser;
```

The command works fine, but only for tables that were already created. It doesn't however auto grant privileges when a new table is added. To fix it, I changed the default settings ([docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html)):

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA myschema GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO myuser;

ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA myschema GRANT SELECT ON SEQUENCES TO myuser;
```

But the commands above don't solve the issue. But if grant privileges `ALL`, not `SELECT`, everything is ok:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA myschema GRANT ALL ON TABLES TO myuser;

ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA myschema GRANT ALL ON SEQUENCES TO myuser;
```

How can I grant to `myuser` only `SELECT` privileges for all the tables that will be created later in schema `myschema`?

Comment: Do you have a list of command to reproduce your problem? It seems to work fine for me. Also, which version are you running?

Comment: You have to `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR` the `ROLE` that will create the tables.